# Log when entity framework 6 SqlAzureExecutionStrategy retries

Tags: entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database

How can I log when the SqlAzureExecutionStrategy retries an Entity Framework operation? When using the transient fault handling logic with regular SqlConnection calls, a Retrying event is exposed. Is there something similar when using the SqlAzureExecutionStrategy with Entity Framework 6? If not, what are some other options?

Comment: There is a very good article on this topic explaining all the steps for logging Azure SQL database with ASP.NET MVC and EntityFramework:. Hope this helps. Here is the link to it: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/connection-resiliency-and-command-interception-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 2):

> There is a very good article on this topic explaining all the steps for logging Azure SQL database with ASP.NET MVC and EntityFramework:. Hope this helps. Here is the link to it: asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/… –  ACS yesterday

As stated in the comment by [ACS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/570899/acs), this [guide](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/connection-resiliency-and-command-interception-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) discusses connection resiliency and command interception for Entity Framework.This document discusses how to built the retry logic in EF6 and how to create a logging interface and class to log the events.

In addition to the previous link, there is a topic which discusses [connection resiliency/retry logic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456835.aspx) in EF6 and its [limitations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn307226).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a way with interceptions to detect the Retry events ONLY and log current retry count and delay for these events?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom ExecutionStrategy which inherits from the SqlAzureExecutionStrategy, and override the ShouldRetryOn method:

```
public class LoggedSqlAzureExecutionStrategy : SqlAzureExecutionStrategy
{
  protected override bool ShouldRetryOn(Exception exception)
  {
    var shouldRetry = base.ShouldRetryOn(exception);
    if (shouldRetry)
    {
      // log exception   
    }

    return shouldRetry;
  }
}
```