# How to log in Entity Framework Core UseSqlServer Retries

Tags: c#, sql-server, logging, ef-core-2.1

I have configured Retries Policies in `DbContextOptionsBuilder.UseSqlServer` using Entity Framework Core 2.1.

Here is the code sample:

```
DbContextOptionsBuilder<T> builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<T>();
builder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString, sqloptions => {
                sqloptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(
                    maxRetryCount: 5,
                    maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                    errorNumbersToAdd: new List<int>(){});
            });
```

The code above works but I do not know how to add logging during the retries process.

I have checked a related question here: [azure sql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28949069/log-when-entity-framework-6-sqlazureexecutionstrategy-retries) but that question is related to entity framework 6 and sql azure.

Could anyone suggest how to add logging in the retries policies? For example, during the retries process, it will print a log saying waiting for retries #1 out of #5 for example?

Thank you.

Comment: You can turn on diagnostics in server.  Not sure if the retry goes into logger.  See : https://damienbod.com/2016/12/13/ef-core-diagnosis-and-features-with-ms-sql-server/

Answer (score 2):

You can add logging to your DbContext in OnConfiguring method. UseLoggerFactory method takes LoggerFactory, this is asp.net core loggerFactory.

This should write retries to your log.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(LoggerFactory);
}
```

You can find detailed information [here.](https://elanderson.net/2018/10/entity-framework-core-logging/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do I set the logging during the retry process?

Comment: You don't set it in retry process. You can set it overall in OnConfiguring method, I wrote above.

Comment: do you have any progress?

Comment: sorry for the late response. I inherit `SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy` as I am required to add cancellationtoken. So I used NLog in that inherited class. Thanks for your help anyway.